# How to change a firefox option on a quick way (via shortcuts, command line,..)?

Tags: command-line, configuration, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox, options

In Firefox we have two options at `Firefox->Preferences->Preferences->Fonts and colors->Colors` menu, `Use system colors` and `Sites can use other colors`.

I would like keep the first one checked (and this is ok) and change the second on a quick way.

A quick way could be pressing a shortcut on keyboard, running a terminal command or changing a content of a config file (because I can do a shell script and use a keyboard command).

My motivation is I would like to always use my system colors but if a webpage has strange visuals, I'd like change it to the original quickly.

Any ideas?

Comment: IIRC, the firefox config is in a sqlite database, you could probably set up a script to update it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understood what you're trying to achieve, but there're addons that seem related, e.g. [Color toggle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/color-toggle/) or [ToggleDocumentColors_](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/toggledocumentcolors-198916/) (among many others, I guess).

Comment: Thx sr_, a similar extension is PrefsBar and works to me.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/313483/how-do-i-change-firefoxs-aboutconfig-from-a-shell-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found a solution...

I asked on mozilla forum and they returned a answer to me. The solution is:

Install a extension called [PrefBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/prefbar/). With this extension we can put a checkbox on mozilla that will change the property `browser.display.use_document_colors`. We can set a shorcut too (for example, F1).

With this extension we can enable severel other options too.

Comment: Extension is removed firefox said... I don't want to rely on such things, I'm looking for way to do that via bash. Or post extension source code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about editing firefox config files manually is a good idea, and according to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/A_Brief_Guide_to_Mozilla_Preferences#files) one shouldn't. However, if you wish to avoid going through `Firefox->Preferences->...` you can open up a new tab with the address `about:config?filter=color` and toggle the value of `browser.display.use_system_colors` in the last column. This is the recommended way to edit Firefox preferences as far as I know.

Comment: Thx about comment. Intersting way. The property what I was looking for is `browser.display.use_document_colors` and I can change it using `about:config`. I would keep this in my mind. I had found a solution (uses shortcuts) and I will embrace it. Thx a lot.